How to import other scripts in the same folder?
I'm writing a PyQGIS script and I would import in my script other external scripts. I tried in this way but the code doesn't work.
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import interfaceParam.py, bufferBuilder.py, clipping.py, graphicBuilder.py, endDialog.py

An error says to me: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interfaceParam.py'; 'interfaceParam' is not a package"
Edit: All other scripts are located in the same folder

The path is "C:/Users/Salvo/interfaceParam.py". I tried without .py, I tried with execFile() but nothing. With exec(), I did exec("/Salvo/interfaceParam.py") but an error says to me "invalid Syntax".


exic is not for what you are trying to do.
and what path for file you try to run? Files may be stored in different directories


The directory is just one, isn't it? The path of interfaceParam.py file is "C://Users/Salvo/interfaceParam.py", but also other files are stored in the same folder : I didn't store these files in other directories.

wait, you a trying to run interfaceParam.py in which you are trying to import interfaceParam?

I resolved with
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/Users/Salvo"))
import interfaceParam, bufferBuilder, clipping, etc...

You can prepend the directory where interfaceParam.py is saved to your PATH and then import the script.
In the example the interfaceParam script is imported under the namespace ip.
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, r"C:/directory/where/script/is/saved")

import interfaceParam as ip

ip.myFunction()

Or, import individual functions
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, r"C:/directory/where/script/is/saved")

from interfaceParam import myFunction

myFunction()


you can try:
from . import interfaceParam, bufferBuilder, clipping, graphicBuilder, endDialog

remove ".py" and using point as current directory.
Also:
from {your plugin name} import interfaceParam, bufferBuilder, clipping, graphicBuilder, endDialog

But best way is import not script, but functions or classes from file:
from .interfaceParam import class1, function1, class2


Thanks, but doing in these ways, the console displays the following error: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

then try just import interfaceParam whithout ".py". And how do you run your script? Just from console?

Yes, just from console. I tried with just import interfaceParam, but it raises the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interfaceParam'"
